# Apache Kafka producer read from file one time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new for Kafka. I have created a producer-topic-consumer. When i take data manuel it's not problem producer always open.

But when i try below code (to read from file)

```
 bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test  --new-producer < /home/beyhan/foo.txt
```

Read from file and return

> WARN The configuration topic = null was supplied but isn't a known
>   config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)

and producer stop. I want to always open producer and when i add a new txt file should read always.How can i write a folder and when folder has new txt file read from producer.

Comment: Not sure. I am just wondering what `--new-producer` should be? This flag does not exist. Maybe it messes up command line parsing...

Comment: maybe but i must write that one otherwise doesnt read from file. Do you suggest another way to read data not manual ?

Comment: Cannot follow. This should work: `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test  < /home/beyhan/foo.txt`

Comment: ah no that's still run one time , i want to open txt file and always add this file or read always new files, do you have another suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the command used, that has worked fine for me, though `--new-producer` isn't necessary

> i want to open txt file and always add this file or read always new files

In this case, I would suggest looking into Fluentd or Filebeat rather that writing some producer code.

If you want to use Kafka Connect, you can try [`kafka-connect-spooldir`](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)